# While editing my snippets.json, my newlines are turned into spaces when I use the snippet

Tags: html, json, visual-studio, code-snippets, emmet

I am using VS Code and tring to create some custom emmet snippets. When I try to make a newline in the snippet it places a space instead.

Here is an example code:

```
{
"html": {
    "snippets": {
        "qq": "<div>\n</div>"
        }
    }
}
```

When I use the snippet 'qq' it should return:

```
<div>
</div>
```

But it returns:

```
<div> </div>
```

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

Try to use ${newline} instead. That should produce a new line rather than '\n'.